# how to handle touch event like UITableView or ScollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I made a customer control, inherit from `UIView` and add a lot of `UIButton`s on the `UIView`.
When a user touches and moves I will do some animation: let buttons move by the function `touchesMoved`:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

but buttonClick event seems to have a higher priority.

I want to it can like `UITableView`, scroll things have higher priority then button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look into [UIPanGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

It allows you the ability to cancel events sent to other handlers.

---

Updated with additional information about how to safe previous points.

In the action callback, you gett notified of the initial touch location `recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`. You can save this point as an instance variable. You also get callbacks at various intervals `recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged`. You can save this information also. Then when you get the callback with `recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`, you reset any instance variables.

```
- (void)handler:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:self];
    switch (recognizer.state)
    {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
            self.initialLocation = location;
            self.lastLocation = location;
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
            // Whatever work you need to do.
            // location is the current point.
            // self.lastLocation is the location from the previous call.
            // self.initialLocation is the location when the touch began.

            // NOTE: The last thing to do is set last location for the next time we're called.
            self.lastLocation = location;
            break;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: i dont know how to use UIPanGesture to get prevpoint,like this CGPoint prevPoint = [[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0] previousLocationInView:[self superview]];

Comment: because i need to calculate the angle for CGAffineTransformRotate by  3 point touch prevpoint curpoint and center. like this angleWithCenterPoint:anchroPoit andStartPoint:prevPoint andEndPoint:curPoint

Comment: actually i dont know how to use UIPanGestureRecognizer instead of touchesMoved,but on the contrary i used UITapGestureRecognizer and UILabel instead of UIButton. It solve the problem. and thank you